# Break event into separate strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, events

I have the following incoming event:

```
{
  "reported": {
    "value": 11,
    "sys": "sy1002",
    "ts": "2019-03-30T18:18:00.013Z"
  }
}
```

I want to add "sys" into a separate string. I do the below, but I know that I am missing how to point towards reported somehow.

`event.reported` doesn't work. How do I solve the problem?

```
sys=str(event['sys'])
```

Comment: `sys = event['reported']['sys']`

Comment: `sys` is the name of a standard module though, so probably not a good variable name...

Comment: I wrote sys in this post, reality is different. Many thanks for the respons, it worked!